# Typescript version not playing nicely with react-scripts and ts-loader version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am having trouble using `react-scripts`, `typescript`, and `ts-loader` all the in the same project. I cannot use the most recent version of `typescript` with `react-scripts` because `react-scripts` version 5.0.1 can only work with `typescript` version 3.9.2 or below. However, `ts-loader` can only work with the most recent version of `typescript`. How can I satisfy all these constraints so that I can use all three of these packages?

Comment: Either you'd need to downgrade TS to 3.9.2 and downgrade ts-loader to a version that supports it, or update react-scripts to a version that supports a higher TS version.

Answer (score 0):

CRA seems to work fine with TypeScript 5. So, if you need a temporary workaround for the error and happy to continue working with it, you can achieve that by creating a new overrides section in your package.json (if not existing already), and adding the same typescript version in dependences to it.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13080 maybe this can help you

Comment: You should add the important point to take from the link you share in case the issue is not accessible anymore and it will help to find the information needed.